# xpath is not working in HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using XPath, HtmlUnitDriver & FirefoxDriver.

Here is the my xpath to click on the signin button. When I use XPath

```
//div[@id='mainPane']/form/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/a[2]
```

to click on sign in button then it  is working fine with FirefoxDriver but not working in HtmlUnitDriver.I have also enabled &  disabled the javascript in HtmlUnitDriver.But not working.

I am getting Error:- When I click on this sign in button using HtmlUnitDriver,then it is not redirecting to next page,but in FirefoxDriver,it is redirecting to next page.Here is my code:-

```
 HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(false);
 WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainPane']/form/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/a[2]"));
 webElement.click();
```

Please guide me.

Comment: What error do you get from HtmlUnit?

Comment: @ David Grant: I have added the more details in the question.

Comment: What is the content of the `a` element?

Comment: @David Grant: content of **a** element is---> <a href="javascript:if (document.forms.loginform.onsubmit && document.forms.loginform.onsubmit()) document.forms.loginform.submit()" onclick="">

Comment: Does HtmlUnit complain about the javascript?

Comment: @David Grant: When I set **false**,then it doesn't complain about javascript,but when I set **true**,then it gives exception **Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement [link](http://sales.liveperson.net/hcp/html/mTag.js?site=7824460#1(eval)#1)**.

Comment: @dhananjay What was the solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As @David Grant suggests your problem might be related to the Javascript.
Enable your javascript in the HtmlUnitDrive -

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```